# why does the value of the cell in the array produce 0 when run?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Why does `SchoolData[1][1]` (the user's name or score or whatever) always give 0?

```
score=0
Class = 0
for x in range (0,3):  # the number of times I want the user to complete the quiz
    print ("Enter your name")
    name = input()
    print ("what class")
    Class = input()

    print("1. 9+10=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)

    if answer == 19:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")

    print("2. 16+40=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)

    if answer == 56:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")

    print("3. 5+21=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)

    if answer == 26:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")

    print("4. 5-6=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)

    if answer == -1:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")

    print("5. 21-9=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)

    if answer == 12:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")

SchoolData=[[0 for x in range(3)] for x in range(3)]  #this is the array
SchoolData[x][0]=name  #this is the users name enter code here
SchoolData[x][1]=score  #this is the score obtained by the user
SchoolData[x][2]=Class  #this is the users class number
raise SystemExit
```

I run the code and complete the quiz 3 times.  I want to know the first user's name, score and class number.  I tried extracting the information out of the cell in the array.

Comment: I think you have intendation issues, the lines SchoolData=[[...]] and below need to be within the for-loop. What do you expect SchoolData to look like?

Comment: so when i type in for example lets say i want to know( when the quiz is run 3 times by 3 different users) the first users name or score or class 1. so for example i am the teacher of the class i just want to know this and this students score and their name by extracting that info from the array.

Answer (score 0):

`SchoolData[1][1]` Gives you the second element of the second list in your nested lists.

`SchoolData=[[0 for x in range(3)] for x in range(3)]` will give you the output: `[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]` which I expect isn't quite what you want.

Without getting into objects, one way you can do what it is you want quick and dirty is like so (assuming you're using python 3.X based on your use of input):

```
import collections
school_data = []
questions = ['9+10', '16+40', '5+21', '5-6', '21-9']  

QuizData = collections.namedtuple('QuizData', 'name,class_code,score')
for x in range(0, 5):
    name = input('Enter your name: ')
    class_code = input('Enter class: ')
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = int(input(question+' = '))
        if answer == eval(question):
            print('Correct!')
            score += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
    q = QuizData(name, class_code, score)
    school_data.append(q)
```

This example uses namedtuples [(python docs)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) inside of lists [(python docs)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html).

To see the highest scores in class 2 you would do like so:

```
highest_scores = sorted([quiz for quiz in school_data if quiz.class_code == '2'], key=lambda q: q.score, reverse=True)
```

This returns a list of QuizData namedtuples sorted by high to low where the class_code was '2'. Note that you have saved class_code as a string and not an integer.

Now, if you want to access the data after the fact you'll need to save it. A simple way would be to use the `csv` module.

```
import csv
with open('quiz_data.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    quiz_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    quiz_writer.writerow(['Name', 'Class_Code', 'Score'])  # header row
    quiz_writer.writerows(school_data)
```

Comment: oh i thought that was establishing the array like a table and it being a 3 by 3 table with 3 users on the rows and name of user, score of that user and class number of that user as columns.

Comment: so how would i, for example as a teacher, get the information of the second user running the quiz like e.g their score, name or class number? what would i have to type in?

Comment: school_data[1] will return the dictionary in the second place in the list; in key, value pairs. The keys will be `name`, `class_code`, and `score`.

Comment: ok thanks a lot man, but say if i ran this quiz 9 times(3 students per class so 3 class's) making some adjustments to the code, how would i say for e.g get the highest to lowest scores in a specific class like class 1?

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated my answer now that I'm out of class @jazzy, I hope this helps!